# java Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server

Tags: java, python, mysql, remote-server

I have made a program that connects with a remote database. I used a database on my web hosting as the database. Within previous months it works fine. But since yesterday, it shows errors:
Java:-

---

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```

---

so I just try to check the connection on python, but it also gave me an error:

***TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond***

Also, I tried connecting to another remote database from the same code, It connects without any error. So what should I do next? plz help

Comment: Check your hosting. It's clearly a problem on that end.

Comment: Is there a specifc cuase why you didn't provide the connectionstirn and code,w hich couöld be a problem. Timeout means you gave the connectionstring a Ip or host and port and this could not reach the server, so check with your provider, he should have a tutorial for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use DBveaver ([enter link description here](https://dbeaver.io/)) client to connect to your database. 
Test the connectivity then try to connect using code. This will help you to debug the issue easier.